# Typescript generic function calling addEventListener works with unexpected parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a helper function that accepts an object, an event type, and a callback. The function calls the `addEventListener` method on the object, passing along the other parameters. It returns a function, that when called, removes the event listener.

I'd like to be able to call this with different object types like HTMLElement, Document, or Window. But since they don't inherit from any particular class, I'm creating a generic function.

```
interface EventSender<Type, ParameterType> {
    addEventListener(t: Type, listener: (evt: ParameterType) => unknown): void;
    removeEventListener(t: Type, listener: (evt: ParameterType) => unknown): void;
}

function myAddEventListener
<Type, ParameterType, Sender extends EventSender<Type, ParameterType>>
(o: Sender, t: Type, listener: (evt: ParameterType) => unknown) {
    o.addEventListener(t, listener);
    return () => o.removeEventListener(t, listener);
}
```

Typescript doesn't complain when I try to use it like the following. I'd expect this to fail. `Document` and `Window`'s `addEventListener` don't accept `number[]` as their first parameter. Shouldn't this violate the constraint on EventSender?

```
myAddEventListener<number[], string, Document>(document, [1, 2, 3], (_x: string) => undefined); // Compiles
myAddEventListener<number[], string, Window>(window, [1, 2, 3], (_x: string) => undefined); // Compiles
```

When I try to call the methods directly, Typescript gives me compiler errors as expected.

```
document.addEventListener([1, 2, 3], (_x: string) => undefined); // Compiler Error: No overload matches this call
window.addEventListener([1, 2, 3], (_x: string) => undefined); // Compiler Error: No overload matches this call
```

And when I create my own type that (I believe) uses the same signatures for `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` as `Document`, Typescript complains (which I'd expect).

```
type DocumentAddEventListenerParams = Parameters<typeof Document.prototype.addEventListener>;
type DocumentAddEventListenerReturn = ReturnType<typeof Document.prototype.addEventListener>;
type DocumentRemoveEventListenerParams = Parameters<typeof Document.prototype.removeEventListener>;
type DocumentRemoveEventListenerReturn = ReturnType<typeof Document.prototype.removeEventListener>;
    
class Foo {
    addEventListener(...params: DocumentAddEventListenerParams): DocumentAddEventListenerReturn {
        return;
    }
    removeEventListener(...params: DocumentRemoveEventListenerParams): DocumentRemoveEventListenerReturn {
        return;
    }
}

myAddEventListener<number[], string, Foo>(new Foo(), '[1, 2, 3]', (_x: string) => undefined); // Compiler Error: Type 'Foo' does not satisfy the constraint 'EventSender<number[], string>'.
```

So why do the first examples succeed while the latter examples fail? I would expect them all to fail for not satisfying the generic constraints.

[Here's a link to a Playground for the above code.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLgMpYCbQA8AKgJ4AOEANMgApxRwC2EkUZlAfMgN4BQyQcjh48GLGAAywAM6QQ0ABRgAXMg7VkAG1nzoaxRHSq6DZq2gaAlMgC83AK4gA1iAD2AdxBW16N8DwAbgEhKAgmN0xxcGk5LCUTDRodOIUoAyMTekYWNms7Rxd3Lx9kPwDggF8+PhgnBDBgNxBkJlIAQVFoqV14qD4SCk1s8zyhmlwQAihkCAAPeTwZNEwcfCIk0xyLdiHOTj5FNzVJ6ZpE8e1etIzjNRHcyyGbe2QnV09vXhDBNwA6ERiVY9VIJZLXaBWYJCZBhMAOKAtRQvbj-MIRKLA2J6KDKcGgqBQvjVPhtTpAiTYvqEEAOJgAI2gAG0ALo0ORQUAAcxoABE3Ag6RJOIo8AKheAaEyAIw0ABMNAAzGzkIoAPpzNQc7kot5TCAwUAQPBQ5AAejNyAAwm4mORgFoIDJSR0uliIVAaXTGVBWeywJyQDzkAB1UBijwijzhzxS2XIBXIZU0dWa5DaoO6pwEQ0KE2Bc2Wm12h1OmpiwUscAAt2Uj2KGXypUq1NagM6gp6nNG-OF622+2OmaoKBQNzpZAAOTcyEi0C0bhErTgYAQAAsncgwGvZMgEHAtFo+NGpp4axSYvXGwnmymNW3A1ys-rc8bTRb+yWh2hR+O1NPZ0wKAFyXJgV3XTdt13fdDxqMAhmQflKwkcluipNIHmWWwtlGaAZEIeDKDcGBEPFKswD+cgxzANxCIgc80I9Thgjo0jkPAVD3QJAAlVgERabDePhRENAIoZiLYiUKKo2jaKGBiuJxZi+FYpCpN4jEIEYglMLsHDHigfC6IktTyMo6i5MoP50TnbSlJYhDTIkDTbMUvohP4vSPJEoYxKIkinOrGSaLo6zwlcusCWUmE+AQLQ4BkZYADE3BnfgYUBOy+kUP5crVcgzCYGQ1ECsBOMinFMNKUrysvHi+MRb4YRhOF+OhIRqha8LMQq7Lcr+fLCuKyTyJcnq6sqobqrI5zuq0ty0m8lp0uawRWsRdrBGqEkyVrCbqVpBlmRVDNgxStwRQUDxkHO5EaAAcmvRNlXuu801O59uzzd8iwHUth1-CcNGQe7zvu5AxU3dwwHTFdZBgUgtw3Pdmg5OBQBh+7ulOIhDp9P103bINOHuv4gA)

Comment: Since `addEventListener` has multiple overloads, you would need to have a type that infers multiple overloads if any - and this would only work up to a certain predefined limit.